# Split the overlapping time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a requirement to equally split the duration for records which has overlapping in the datetime.

Example:
[image: Refer this picture for example]

As per the example, if I calculate total runtime of the machine for Order 1, it is 3 hours. But I want it to be 2 hours because in the same machine another order ran between that duration (From 9 AM to 11 AM).

I tried searching the form, and all are pointed to exclude the overlapping duration or doing some other functionality. But I want to split the overlapping duration for all the records.

Sample Table Structure:

```
declare @st datetime, @et datetime;

DECLARE @table TABLE (Machine varchar(4),OrderId varchar(6),StartTime DateTime2, EndTime DateTime2)

INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'M2','ORD1','2017-11-01 10:30:00.000', '2017-11-01 12:00:00.000'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'M2','ORD2','2017-11-01 11:00:00.000', '2017-11-01 12:30:00.000'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'M2','ORD3','2017-11-01 11:30:00.000', '2017-11-01 13:00:00.000'
```

Expected Result:
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZG9r.png)

Based on the above picture,
Duration for ORD1 = 30 MIN + 15 MIN (30 MIN overlap between ORD1 and ORD2) + 10 MIN (30 MIN overlap between ORD1, ORD2 and  ORD3)
Duration for ORD2 = 15 MIN + 10 MIN + 15 MIN
Duration for ORD3 = 10 MIN + 15 MIN + 30 MIN

Total Machine Run time will be 55 + 40 + 55 = 150 MIN (2 Hours and 30 MIN)

Thanks,
Aravinth

Comment: Sure, but what's your table structure? You should show it with some sample data, too.

Comment: I have added the sample table structure.

Comment: if the start time is 10:30 and end time is 11:00 it will considered as 1 hr or 30 mnts

Comment: @Aravinth Very good. Now, add the output you are looking for based on this sample data.

Comment: It will be 30 minutes. But if another record falls in the same range, then we need to split the time for Record 1 as 15 minutes and Record 2 as 15 minutes.

Comment: @gotqn I have added expected result as well.

Comment: Are you looking for the 55/40/55 minute detail by `OrderId`? Or just the 150 min total? If its the latter, why not take the `datediff(mi, min(StartTime), max(EndTime))`, as that would also evaluate to 150?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the response. Finally this scenario has been covered with the help of one of our team member. Below is the solution,

```
 DECLARE @table TABLE (OrdId varchar(12),MId varchar(4), ST DateTime, ET DateTime)

INSERT INTO @table SELECT '10001','M1','2017-11-01 10:30:00.000', '2017-11-01 12:00:00.000' INSERT INTO @table SELECT '10002','M1','2017-11-01 11:00:00.000', '2017-11-01 12:30:00.000' INSERT INTO @table SELECT '10003','M1','2017-11-01 11:30:00.000', '2017-11-01 14:00:00.000'  INSERT INTO @table SELECT '10004','M2','2017-11-01 14:30:00.000', '2017-11-01 16:00:00.000' 

DECLARE @ST datetime, @ET datetime, @NEXT_ST datetime, @RC smallint, @MCHr smallint; set @MCHr = 0; set @ST = (select MIN(ST) AS ST from @table where  MId = 'M1' and OrdId = '10001') set @ET = (select MAX(ET) AS ET from @table where  MId = 'M1' and OrdId = '10001') WHILE @ST < @ET  BEGIN
       set @NEXT_ST = (select MIN(ST) AS ST from @table where  MId = 'M1' and ST > @ST)
       if @NEXT_ST is not null
              begin
                     set @RC = ( SELECT count(*) from @table where MId = 'M1' and (@ST >= ST and @ST < @NEXT_ST))
                     if @RC > 0
                     begin
                           SET @MCHr  = @MCHr + (select DATEDIFF(MI,0,@NEXT_ST-@ST) / @RC);
                     end;
                     set @ST = @NEXT_ST;
              end;
       else
              begin
                     set @NEXT_ST = (select MIN(ET) AS ET from @table where  MId = 'M1' and (@ST >= ST and @ST < ET))
                     set @RC = ( SELECT count(*) from @table where MId = 'M1' and (@ST >= ST and @ST < ET))
                     if @RC > 0
                           SET @MCHr  = @MCHr + (select DATEDIFF(MI,0,@NEXT_ST-@ST) / @RC)
                     set @ST = @NEXT_ST;
              end; END; select @MCHr as MCHr
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use "window functions" to determine the overall span then divide by number of orders processed, along these lines:

```
select
  machine, order, datetime_start, datetime_end
, min(datetime_start) over(partition by machine, order, date(datetime_start)) min_dt
, max(datetime_start) over(partition by machine, order, date(datetime_start)) max_dt
, count(*) over(partition by machine, order, date(datetime_start)) num

, datediff(ss,min(datetime_start) over(partition by machine, order, date(datetime_start))
             ,max(datetime_start) over(partition by machine, order, date(datetime_start))) 
  / count(*) over(partition by machine, order) as equal_duration
from (
    select * from your_query here
     )
```

For more; we would need much more detail from you.

Comment: Hi, Please let me know the details you need. So that, I can provide the same.